# A double inequality by Ramanujan

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Ramanujan presented this double inequality without showing a proof, namely: 
$$\sqrt\pi \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}\left(8x^3+4x^2+x+\frac{1}{100} \right)^{1/6}<\Gamma(x+1)<\sqrt\pi \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}\left(8x^3+4x^2+x+\frac{1}{30} \right)^{1/6}, \space x \ge 0$$
I wonder if there is a nice proof for it. Could you help here? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a source for the inequality? Thanks.

Comment: @daniel: I know the problem from my brother Chris and he knows it from his teacher. I can't tell you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably explained in this paper or its references.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1896

Comment: Nice paper! (+1)